# Apache and NodeJS over SSL

Tags: node.js, apache, ssl-certificate

I need to switch from HTTP to HTTPS to be able to use the getUsermedia for webrtc implementation. I've installed certificates on my Apache version 2.2.22 and got it working.

In the website I'm hosting NodeJS is used. Perhaps not the ideal setup but I've encountered problems when socket.io on the client wants to communicate with the NodeJS server.

In the console this message appears:

```
GET https://mydomain.nl:1900/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1449219985177-166 net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

It's obvious to me that the NodeJS server app can't handle requests over HTTPS because it's an HTTP server.

I want to alter that server to be able to serve HTTPS requests using the SSL already in place on the apache webserver.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 23):

I recommend to have a look apache's [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html). This would allow you to run the external requests over the apache SSL pipeline. The node.js can run only on the localhost interface without ssl support because it's proxy'd by apache. I you configure a vhost it could look like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerName www.yourserver.com
  DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/www.yourserver.com/public_html

  CustomLog <LOG-PATH> combined
  ErrorLog <ERROR-LOG-PATH>

  # Example SSL configuration
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
  SSLCertificateFile "<CERT-PATH>/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "<CERT-PATH>/server.key"

  ProxyPass /<PATH>/ http://localhost:1900/
  ProxyPassReverse /<PATH>/ http://myserver:1900/
</VirtualHost>
```

Your reguest would then look like this:

```
GET https://mydomain.nl/<PATH>/?....
```

Where `<PATH>` has the same value as in the vhost config's `<ProxyPass>` directive.

Comment: Ok, when adding the proxyPass and ProxyPassReverse i get the following error: Failed to start apache :

Starting web server: apache2Syntax error on line 15 of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/webmin.1446455161.conf:
Invalid command 'ProxyPass', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
 failed!
<PATH> should hold the location of the node js server like /var/www/socketserver?

Comment: please run `apachectl configtest`  and post the output. secondly please send your vhost.conf (anonymised)

`<PATH>` will be part of the URL. 
e.g.:

`ProxyPass /nodejs/ http://localhost:1900/` 

will result in URL:

`https://myserver.nl/nodejs` and the output will be redirected to `localhost:1900`

Comment: also check if `mod_proxy` is installed and enabled.

Comment: DocumentRoot /var/www/NEWchat
<Directory "/var/www/NEWchat">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerName chat.mydomain
Alias /uploads /var/uploads
ErrorLog /var/transonlylog/log.log
LogLevel emerg
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.mydomain/cert.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.mydomain/privkey.pem
SSLCACertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/chat.mydomain/chain.pem
ProxyPass /var/www/TO-Socket/ http://localhost:1900/
ProxyPassReverse /var/www/TO-Socket/ http://mydomain:1900/

Comment: Yes, installed it. Had to run  a2enmod proxy_http which i hound here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/58179/install-mod-proxy-to-get-proxypass-to-work

Comment: Now i'm getting this: GET https://mydomain.nl/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1449224333400-4 net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE

Comment: Ok, I recommend a step by step approach.  For now remove the proxy statements and put just a simple  _HelloWorld_ `index.html` in the directory `/var/www/NEWchat` and call the url `http://mydomain.nl`  in browser and check if the html page shows the _HelloWorld_ content

Comment: There's allready an index.html at that location (login page) and that gets served well with and without proxy statements. When i log in the chat starts and communication with the socketserver is needed. Right now it's complaining about:No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Comment: Ok, but now we are facing an cors issue. Please check if the header is present on both sides (Apache and NodeJS)? As well as the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` directive.

Comment: I added this to the htaccess: Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" Not sure how to do it on the nodejs cause i only find thing in combination with express.

Comment: I recommend tu open another topic for the cors related stuff. because we're getting quite off-topic. Back to the initial question, you can do *for testing only* start chrome with `chromium-browser --disable-web-security` this would avoid the cors issue. so you test if the proxy thing is running.

Comment: Ok with security disabled: GET https://mydomain.nl/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1449228225229-11 404 (Not Found)

Comment: ... and in the vhost looks like this  `ProxyPass /socket.io/ http://localhost:1900/`  and  `ProxyPassReverse /socket.io/ http://localhost:1900/`  ?

Comment: Dierectives apache: ProxyPass /socket/ http://localhost:1900/
ProxyPassReverse /socket/  http://mydomain.nl:1900/       connect to it on client: socket = io.connect('https://mydomain.nl/socket:1900');

Comment: perhaps it's an idea you look with me via teamview? :-)

Comment: But when you try to open `https://mydomain.nl/socket.io/...` the vhost must look like I show in the comment before. Because `/socket/` doesn't map to your URL `/socket.io`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96978/discussion-between-frw-and-ingridsede).

Comment: opened  a new question with -i hope- a somewhat clearer outlne. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097491/apache-hosting-php-website-and-proxy-for-node-js-cors

Comment: THANKS, THANKS, THANKS

Comment: This is awesome! I like this answer the most because in my case i needed it to be working on the exact same domain (no subdomain) so the browser could send the logged in user cookie session id which is only sent for the same domain and not subdomains - also this is great for using ajax same domain policy. So happy now I can run php on apache and nodejs also via apache, both systems via the same domain and using SSL! Just Brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

Solved it by creating a seperate Vhost as proxy for the Node js. Named it socket.mydomain.nl and everything works well

Answer (score 2):

proxy nodejs

```
var proxy = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer();
var fs = require('fs');

express = require('express.io');
app = express();


var SSloptions = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('/var/www/node/certificados/mig.xxx.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('/var/www/node/certificados/xxx.crt'),    
    ca: [
        fs.readFileSync('/var/www/node/certificados/gd_bundle-xx.crt')
    ],
    rejectUnauthorized: false,
    requestCert: true,
    agent: false,
    strictSSL: false
};


app.https(SSloptions).io();


app.all('*', function(req, res){
    proxy.web(req, res, {

        target: 'http://localhost:4443',
    });    
});



app.listen(14443);
```